# Creating a activity stream from a set of different tables.

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a site where users can perform certain actions: post a photo, make a comment, watch a video etc.  Each of these actions results in a row being created in a MySQL table with a UNIX timestamp - PhotoPosts, Comments, VideoView etc.

I am looking to build a profile page where users can view everything they've been doing on the site.

I'm wondering, is there a way to query my DB to send me back a selection of different rows from the various tables?

Comment: Yes - Write a query for each table then UNION the results together.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Yii, for example like this

```
$user = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('id, username, profile')
    ->from('tbl_user u')
    ->join('tbl_profile p', 'u.id=p.user_id')
    ->where('id=:id', array(':id'=>$id))
    ->queryRow();
```

More Information you will find here: 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder

Answer (score 0):

I have done this

```
    public function actionSearch() {
    $this->keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
    $pages = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('url as id, name, CONCAT_WS(" ", content) as text, "page" as type')
            //->select('id, name, content as text, "page1" as type')
            ->from('Page')
            ->where('content LIKE :keyword AND status="active"')
            ->getText();

    $events = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('date as id, name, CONCAT_WS(" ", teaser_text, text) as text, "event" as type')
            ->from('Event')
            ->where('CONCAT_WS(" ", teaser_text, text) LIKE :keyword AND status="active"')
            ->getText();

    $news = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('id, name, CONCAT_WS(" ", teaser_text, text) as text, "news" as type')
            ->from('News')
            ->where('CONCAT_WS(" ", teaser_text, text) LIKE :keyword AND status="active"')
            ->getText();

    $programmes = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('id, name, CONCAT_WS(" ", teaser_text, text) as text, "programme" as type')
            ->from('Programme')
            ->where('CONCAT_WS(" ", teaser_text, text) LIKE :keyword AND status="active"')
            ->getText();

    $union = $programmes . ' UNION (' . $events. ') UNION (' . $news. ') UNION (' . $pages . ')';
    $records = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($union)->bindValue(':keyword', '% ' . $this->keyword . ' %')->queryAll();


    $dataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($records, array(
        'id'=>'id',
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>6,
        ),
    ));

    $this->render('search',array(
        'keyword'=>$this->keyword,
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

My search looks like

```
            <section class="search-results">
                <h1>Search Results - <?php echo $keyword?></h1>
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'id'=>'search',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_search_view',
    'template'=>'{items} {pager}',
    'itemsTagName'=>'ul',
    'itemsCssClass'=>'results-list',
    'pager' => array(
        'header' => '',
        'maxButtonCount' => 10
    ), 
)); ?>
            </section><!-- end search-results -->
```

You get the point. I have also implemented this http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/audittrail2/ for another part of the website. It is rather cool, it gathers all the actions in 1 table.